# Roman to Integer using STL in C++

Tags: c++, vector, split, stl, maps

I'm new to STL, I was trying to convert the Roman numerals into their corresponding integers using maps and vectors. But, my outputs are varying a lot and aren't accurate. For Instance output for **"X"** is 20 but output for **"XI"** is 12. I am taking string as an input and then splitting it up into characters and storing them in vectors. Then passing that vector into the function, which basically computes the Romans to the integers.
Here's what I've tried:-

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void roman_int(vector<char> &s){
   map<char,int> roman;
   roman['M'] = 1000;
   roman['D'] = 500;
   roman['C'] = 100;
   roman['L'] = 50;
   roman['X'] = 10;
   roman['V'] = 5;
   roman['I'] = 1;
   
   int res=0;
   for(int i=0;i<s.size();++i){
       if(roman[s[i]]<roman[s[i+1]]){
           res -= roman[s[i]];
       }
       else{
           res += roman[s[i]];
       }
   }
   res += roman[s[s.size()-1]];
   cout<<res;
}

int main(){
    string numeral;
    cin>>numeral;
    
    vector<char> s(numeral.begin(), numeral.end()); //Splitting the string to characters
    
    roman_int(s);
}
```

Comment: Could you please state a clear question? Otherwise others cannot help you that well.

Comment: Be careful: `s[i+1]` is out-of-range when `i = s.size() - 1`

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger to step through the execution of your code (basically execute one line at a time, and look at the various values after each step), you would immediately see some of the problems with your code. Compiling with various debug modes (say `-fsanitize=address` with gcc or clang for instance) may also help.

Comment: Please try TDD (or BDD): here is starting point using catch2 https://godbolt.org/z/4MxG7b9ea as you can see your code fails on simplest test case.

Comment: One line to remove and you are much closer to proper solution.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want to have for(int i=0;i<s.size()-1;++i)

Comment: You are right, it was executing for the last character one extra time, and I assume because of s[i+1] index is it?

Comment: Removing `res += roman[s[s.size()-1]];`  also does the same thing, as it causes one extra iteration for the last character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop seems to run more than needed.

```cpp
 int res=0;
   for(int i=0;i<s.size();++i){
       if(roman[s[i]]<roman[s[i+1]]){
           res -= roman[s[i]];
       }
       else{
           res += roman[s[i]];
       }
   }
   res += roman[s[s.size()-1]];
   cout<<res;
```

There is another iteration at the end of the for loop which causes the last element to be added twice. To fix it remove the last iteration `res += roman[s[s.size()-1]];` or subtract 1 from the for loop's condition `for(int i=0;i<s.size()-1;++i)`.